# Delete a belongsTo Association

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

There's surprisingly little information to be found about this and I guess I've never run into it before, but I'm in a situation where I have a model with a `belongsTo` relationship. The model is the key and when I delete a record, I need to ensure that its associated record is also deleted.

Specifically, I have a `Building` model that `belongsTo` an `Address`. When I delete the building, I need to be sure that the associated address is also deleted.

I can't flag the association as dependent, of course, so is a callback the best way to ensure that the address record gets deleted or is there a better way? This is one of those cases where I know I can do it with a callback, but at a visceral level, it seems like there should be a better way. I'm wondering whether that's the case.

Thanks.

Comment: If Building and Address have a hasOne/belongsTo association, why not just keep the address in the Building table?

Comment: Several different models (e.g. Building, Contractor, Company) have address values and I wanted to consolidate those fields.

Comment: why not using Foreign Keys in the database and select `on DELETE CASCADE`??

Comment: @pleasedontbelong I guess it's a bit of a catch-22. Deleting from the address scares me a little because it's ancillary data (the building is what we "care" about), but at the same time, it's important enough that I want it deleted with the building. It's a good idea, though. Given what I'm working with, it might be the cleanest solution. Add it as an answer and I'll mark it as _the_ answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not using Foreign Keys in the database and select `on DELETE CASCADE` and let the database do the work...

*[Based on the comment]* if you the Address is attached to other models that you dont want to delete, you can set those FK to `ON DELETE RESTRICT` and the building wont be deleted.

And if you need something more complex you can add the beforeDelete() callback in your model, there's an [example in the doc](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1054/beforeDelete)

Good Luck

Comment: I ended up making the `addresses` table polymorphic since that was more accurate/applicable to my needs anyway (now `Building hasOne Address`, for example), but this would've worked perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

In cakephp 3.x you can use the unlink method like described here:

http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.ORM.Association.HasMany.html#_unlink

This would set the foreign key field in the database to null

In your case it should be something like this everytime when you want to delete records from buildings so integrate it in your delete function. Of course it requires properly associations in the models.

```
$address = $this->Addresses->get('address_id'):
$building = $this->Buildings->find()->where(['building_id' => 'some_id'])->toArray();

if ($this->Addresses->association('Buildings')->unlink($address, $building)) { 
    $this->Flash->success(__('Success!'));
    return $this->redirect($this->referer());
} else {
    $this->Flash->error(__('Error.'));
    return $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

Comment: Please improve this answer as [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370).

Comment: Thanks I've removed my comment